# Scrapy: Duplicate item fields due to multiple for loops

Tags: python, scrapy

My question is almost identical to: [Scrapy - Why Item Inside For Loop Has The Same Value While Accessed in Another Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778543/scrapy-why-item-inside-for-loop-has-the-same-value-while-accessed-in-another-p)

Except I have two For loops so creating a new item will cause me to lose the data from the first scraped page.

The basic structure is:

- Know first url.
- For loop through known urls

  - For loop for data and next url

    - For loop for more data and next url

      - Even more data and next url.
      - Even more data and next url.
      - Yield

There are 10-40 pieces of data per page but I have a simplified code that looks for 1-2.

```py
import scrapy


class Product(scrapy.Item):
    Date = scrapy.Field()
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Winner_Name= scrapy.Field()
    Match_Duration= scrapy.Field()
    Loser_Url= scrapy.Field()
    Winner_Birthday= scrapy.Field()
    Loser_Birthday= scrapy.Field()


    pass
```

```py
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from items import Product
start = 2018
finish =2019


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brief"
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS':1,'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':1}

    def start_requests(self):

        urls = "https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/results-archive?year=2018"


        for year in range(start, finish):
            next_page = urljoin(urls,"?year=" + str(year))
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, meta={'dont_obey_robotstxt': True},dont_filter=True)




    def parse(self, response):
        for tournament in response.css('tr.tourney-result'):
                item = Product()
                item['Date']=tournament.css('span.tourney-dates::text').get().replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '').replace("\t", '').strip(),
                item['Name']= tournament.css('span.tourney-title::text').get().replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '').replace("\t", '').strip(),
                Tourney_URL= response.urljoin(tournament.css('a.button-border::attr(href)').get())
                yield scrapy.Request(Tourney_URL, callback=self.tourney_info, meta={'dont_obey_robotstxt': True, 'item':item},dont_filter=True)

    def tourney_info(self, response):
        table = response.css('table.day-table tbody')
        rows = table.css('tr')
        for row in rows:
            item = response.meta['item']
            names = row.css('td.day-table-name a::text').getall()
            item['Winner_Name']= names[0].replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '').replace("\t", '').strip(),
            Match_URL = response.urljoin(row.css('td.day-table-score a::attr(href)').get())
            yield scrapy.Request(Match_URL, callback=self.matchinfo, meta={'dont_obey_robotstxt': True,'item':item},dont_filter=True)



    def matchinfo(self, response):
            item = response.meta['item']
            table = response.css('table.match-stats-table')
            mytime = response.css('td.time::text').get().replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '').replace("\t", '').strip()
            factors = (60, 1, 1 / 60)
            t1 = sum(i * j for i, j in zip(map(int, mytime.split(':')), factors))
            item['Match_Duration'] = t1
            item['Loser_Url']=response.urljoin(response.css('div.player-right-image a::attr(href)').get())
            winner_url = response.urljoin(response.css('div.player-left-image a::attr(href)').get())
            yield scrapy.Request(winner_url, callback=self.winnerinfo, meta={'dont_obey_robotstxt': True,'item':item},dont_filter=True)

    def winnerinfo(self, response):
            item = response.meta['item']
            item['Winner_Birthday'] = response.css('span.table-birthday::text').get().replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '').replace("\t", '').strip()

            yield scrapy.Request(item['Loser_Url'], callback=self.loserinfo, meta={'dont_obey_robotstxt': True, 'item': item},dont_filter=True)

    def loserinfo(self, response):
            item = response.meta['item']
            item['Loser_Birthday'] = response.css('span.table-birthday::text').get().replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '').replace("\t", '').strip()

            yield item
```

Very simplified results are:

- For loop through known urls (working)

  - For loop for data and next url (working)

    - For loop for more data and next url (will give same value for all data in this loop)

      - Even more data and next url. (working)
      - Even more data and next url. (working)
      - Yield

Does Scrapy have a functionality that I'm missing to be able to keep one item through the whole scrape?

Results:

Should be:

```
             A      B      C

             A      D      E

             A      F      G

             B      H      I 

             B      J      K
```

Is:

```
             A      B      C

             A      B      E

             A      B      G

             B      H      I 

             B      H      K
```

Comment: You can filter duplicates in your `pipeline.py`: create a class variable `saved_items = {}` and check it in `process_item()`

Comment: I took out the sentence about duplicate items, since that isn't the primary issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item you are using to store the scraped data is mutable. You should copy it doing item.copy() before passing it to the next request, for example on parse (probably on tourney_info too). Since each method produces a en entry on the json file, but you are holding multiple references to the same item, its expected that this happens.

Check too https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#copying-items if you want.

Comment: This was it. Thanks.